# Uncaught (in promise) Error: {#each} only iterates over array-like objects when using Inertia Persistent Layouts

Tags: javascript, typescript, laravel, svelte, inertiajs

I am currently trying to build a Webapp using Laravel Inertia and Svelte.
When I try to utilize a Persistent Layout and go to another page using a `<Link>` element I get the error:
`Uncaught (in promise) Error: {#each} only iterates over array-like objects when using Layouts` and I do not get redirected.
This only happens if i press on the `<Link>` element and if i directly go to /login or / i have no errors.
Here is the code that is causing this issue:

Welcome.svelte

```
<script context="module">
    export { default as layout } from "../Layouts/GuestLayout.svelte";
</script>

<script>
    import { Link, page } from "@inertiajs/svelte";
    import Card from "@/Components/Card.svelte";
</script>

<div class="min-h-screen">
    {#each $page.props.products as product}
        <Card productImages={product.images} productName={product['name']} productDescription={product['description']} primaryButtonText={"Buy @" + product['product_store']}></Card>
    {/each}
</div>
```

GuestLayout.svelte

```
<script>
    import { Link , page} from "@inertiajs/svelte";
    import Navbar from "@/Components/Navbar.svelte";
    export let canLogin, canRegister;
</script>

<div
    class="min-h-screen flex flex-col"
>
    <Navbar canLogin={canLogin} canRegister={canRegister} user={$page.props.auth.user}></Navbar>

    <slot />
</div>
```

Snippet of Navbar.svelte

```
        {#if canLogin}
            <div class="p-6 text-right">
                {#if $page.props.auth.user}
                    {#if canLogin}
                        <Link href={route("login")}>
                            <button class="hover:text-white">Login</button>
                        </Link>
                    {/if}
                {/if}
            </div>
        {/if}
```

If i comment out the `#each` part in Welcome.svelte or remove the Layout and work without Layouts i don't have issues.
Would be very thankful for any tips on what I'm possibly doing wrong or pointing me in a direction.

Comment: have you checked the content of the variable `$page.props.products` in every case ?

Comment: I just did by printing the value every 0.1 seconds inside of the GuestLayout component. [Here's](https://imgur.com/a/z9MDmmq) a screenshot of the output uploaded to imgur. When i click on the ```<Link>``` element the error instantly appears and afterwards it's undefined.

Comment: so now you know where the issue is. and nothing in your question is related directly to that variable, so we can't help you much.

Comment: @N69S Thanks a ton for the help, I managed to solve the issue :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay so I found out how to solve this issue.
Even though I am not using the `$page.props.products` variable inside of my `GuestLayout.svelte` or `Navbar.svelte` I need to pass it into the `Inertia::render` function on my `/login` route so It's not undefined. 
So I turn this:

```
        return Inertia::render('Auth/Login', [
            'canResetPassword' => Route::has('password.request'),
            'status' => session('status'),
        ]);
```

To this:

```
        return Inertia::render('Auth/Login', [
            'canResetPassword' => Route::has('password.request'),
            'status' => session('status'),
            'products' => []
        ]);
```